# Check for a distinct value in another col before inserting data in the other column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table for which I manually insert the data. Two cols from the table are as below-

```html
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td>**Prod Line **</td>
    <td> **Prod Grp**</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> AA</td>   
    <td> ZA </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> AA  </td>   
    <td> ZB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><STRIKE> CA </STRIKE></td>
    <td> <STRIKE> ZA</STRIKE></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The rule is that **one** **product Grp** can belong to only **one Prod Line**. In other words, one Prod Line can have multiple Prod Grp but not vice versa. This is a DW and the master data is maintained in this table. Recently during manual insertion, I wrongly inserted a line as below(3rd line) and it caused some issues. So, I am wondering is there a way to set a contraint somehow on the table so that the check is done before data insertion? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then it means 1 product group can belong to only one product line so if say product group ZA is already present in table then you should not be allowed to insert it again.

You should have constraint which will not allow you to insert same product group twice.

Add unique constraint on Product Grp

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE NAME] ADD CONSTRAINT [CONSTRAINT_NAME] UNIQUE ([Prod Grp])
```

Comment: There are other columns like modelname, product subgroup etc.                   Model, prod line, prodgrp                                                                                        P123       AA         za                                                                                                Q564       AA        ZA                                                                                                      S874        AA       ZB

Comment: I dont understand. Other columns will not affect constraint. Please let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Hi Abhay, Wouldn't adding unique constraint mean that there can only be one row in the table where prod_grp = 'ZA'(say). The requirement is that the Prd_Grp should belong to only one Prod Line but there can be multiple entries in the table with the same Prod Line-Prod Grp combo(as there are many models that belong to same Prod Line). I hope I am clear!

Comment: You can have unique constraint on model and product group. For one model, product group should be assigned to only one product line. If you have constraint on model and product group, it will ensure that. I may be not correct here but at least you will get an idea of how to achieve this using constraint.